# Gutenberg block get categories in SelectControl

Tags: block-editor

I'm creating a block. I want my block to be able to output posts that can be "filtered". It should be possible to choose from which category the posts should be displayed.
I have gotten so far that I have a function that gives me the categories and you can also select them. Then the values ​​are written in a shortcode. But my problem is, I don't see the select field at first. If I then click somewhere within the editor and then click on my block again, I get to see the SelectControl. If I reload the page and click on my block too quickly, I also get an error that the foreach is empty. How can I make sure that my foreach is already filled before loading my block?

My edit.js

```
function getCategories() {
    const options = [];
    const postCategory = wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'category');
    postCategory.forEach((cat) => {
        options.push({ value: cat.id, label: cat.name });
    });
    return options;
}
```

...

```
<SelectControl
    multiple
    label={__('Cat')}
    options={getCategories()}
    onChange={onChangeCategoriesField}
    value={categories}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that calling `wp.data.select` triggers a fetch and the data takes some time to be available. Until that happens the value returned is an empty array.

My suggestion here is to use `wp.data.useSelect`, which is a React hook made specifically for this, so the component re-renders when there is a change in the data:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

    const categories = useSelect(select =>
        select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'category')
    );

    const [categories_selected, setCategoriesSelected] = useState([]);

    return (
        <SelectControl
            multiple
            label={__('Cat')}
            options={categories.map(({id, name}) => ({label: name, value: id}))}
            onChange={(selected) => {
                // I haven't tested this code so I'm not sure what onChange returns.
                // But assuming it returns an array of selected values:
                setCategoriesSelected(selected)
            }}
            value={categories_selected}
        />
    );
};
```

This will also have the "issue" that the value on the first call of `select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'category')` is empty. So you might want to consider it and return something different in the component if `categories.length === 0`.

If you really need to prevent this from happening, I guess you could call `wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'category')` in your script, close to the top, so when it is called by the component for the first time the data is already in the store.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, declaring my constante does not help me if I declare it before integrating the edit function. 
If I write the code as described by you, how do I get it to the desired position in my sidebar?

Comment: @Tom, you are welcome. I am not sure I understand, which constant declaration do you refer to? What are you refering to with getting the desired position in your sidebar?

Comment: Thanky you. i put wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'category') in my index.js on top. Now it works. Strange :)

Comment: The array will be filled when the selector is called for the first time. That is why if we want it ready the first time `useSelector` is called, we need to call the selector (`wp.data.select` in this case) before that.